# How can I fix this bug on create react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, runtime-error

[How can I fix this bug on create react app? Whenever I run command "npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript have error as shown in image"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMMvN.png)

Comment: please don't put images as question.

Answer (score 0):

in order for your node-webkit to be able to run this command, you must open your terminal with administrator access and then run the command.

So if you are on Windows, follow the steps below:

***For Bash:***

1-Right-click on the "on Windows" application and select Properties.

2-Under the Shortcut tab, click Advanced.

3-Select the Run as administrator checkbox and apply the changes.

***for Command Prompt***

1. Press the Windows Start button at the bottom left.
2. Type in "Command Prompt".
3. Right click on Command Prompt and click "Run as administrator".
4. Click Yes if the Windows 10 User Account Control prompt is displayed.

If you use ***vscode***, just run the app itself with administrator permission:
If you're on Windows you can:

1-Right click the shortcut or app/exe

2-Go to properties

3-Compatibility tab

4-Check "Run this program as an administrator"

For more information, you can refer to the following links:

1-https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810320/17615078

2-https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948482/17615078